# python, count characters in last line string

Tags: python, string

What is the best way in python to count characters ( including whitespace ) from last line ?

Example

```
"AAAAAAA
 BBBB
    CCCCC
         DDD"
```

and the function should return 11 ( 8 whitespace and 3 x D)

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: have you tried a basic combination of len, split and index access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the string from the end([`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)) only once and get the length of last item:

```
>>> s = """AAAAAAA
 BBBB
    CCCCC
         DDD"""

>>> s.rsplit('\n', 1)
['AAAAAAA\n BBBB\n    CCCCC', '         DDD']
#On the other hand simple str.split will split the string more than once:
>>> s.split('\n')
['AAAAAAA', ' BBBB', '    CCCCC', '         DDD']
```

Now simply get the length of last item:

```
>>> len(s.rsplit('\n', 1)[-1])
12
```

With bigger data this is going to be extremely fast:

```
>>> s = """AAAAAAA
 BBBB
    CCCCC
         DDD"""
>>> s = '\n'.join([s]*1000)  #4000 lines
>>> %timeit len(s.split('\n')[-1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.9 µs per loop
>>> %timeit len(s.splitlines()[-1])
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit len(s.rsplit('\n', 1)[-1])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 µs per loop
```

Comment: This must be the best out of current answers because it is optimized for large data.

Answer (score 3):

If that is a single string with embedded newlines, the simple way is to split it into lines and just take the length of the last one.

```
len(s.split('\n')[-1])
```

Comment: Go ahead, punish me for leaving a good answer on a bad question. I can take it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_last_line_len(s)
    return len(s.split('\n')[-1])
```

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvotes.  It was posted within one minute of Mark Ransom's sufficient answer and it is not all that different from it except that it encapsulates the logic into a descriptively named function.  So it is different enough not to be a pure dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string up with [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and then take the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) of the last item, which is index `-1`:

```
>>> len(example.splitlines()[-1])  # It's actually twelve long, not eleven.
12
```